# How to fix rendering problems on Android Studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, rendering

I am trying to develop an android app. But when I create another Activity, the design page displays `Exception raised during rendering: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable_Delegate.nCreateTreeFromCopy(JJ)J`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you should change the preview API level from version 24 to 23, [attached id a screenshot of same issue, if is then solve as above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1eWu.jpg).

If I did not get you, then please clarify. Good luck.

Comment: Helped for me to solve the @ynong123 's problem, thanks a lot!